# ./prereqs-ubuntu.sh Error: Ubuntu focal is not supported

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to use `composer` and for the same I'm using the below command for installation.

`curl -O https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/prereqs-ubuntu.sh`

`chmod u+x prereqs-ubuntu.sh`

These above commands successfully executed.

But when I executed this command `(./prereqs-ubuntu.sh)` then I'm getting below **error**

> **`Terminal Throws Error ///Ubuntu focal is not supported`**

Please help

[Hyperledger Composer Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itNwK.png)

Comment: can you share the stack trace of the error? and also we are not getting what was the problem you are facing and also explain what steps you performed to debug?

Comment: Actually I want to install Hyperledger Composer.

Comment: hyperledger composer is end of life so wouldn't really recommend using it. It's not being maintained anymore and the community has moved on from it.

Answer (score 8):

I also find this kind of error during Hyperledger Composer  installation this problem mainly depends on the Ubuntu version.
Steps to overcome this problem.

1. upgrade ubuntu version as per your ubuntu versoin please follow:

https://www.fosslinux.com/38303/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-20-04-lts-focal-fossa.htm

2. open file **prereqs-ubuntu.sh**  with your compatible editor
3. update  line:

**#Array of supported versions

declare -a versions=('trusty' 'xenial' 'yakkety', 'bionic');**

with

```
# Array of supported versions
declare -a versions=('trusty' 'xenial' 'yakkety', 'bionic', 'focal');
```

4. After saving this file
5. Run command: **./prereqs-ubuntu.sh**

I hope this problem will resolve if anything please feel free to write.